# How to set different color in CSS for focus one for valid and one for invalid

Tags: javascript, css, focus

I want two different color if the value is valid and if it is invalid. 
ym is yearmonth value= yyyymm
lot is a number from 1 to 5
if ym value is null, then we can't give value for lot. thats the code about.

```
function validate() 
{  
   if(document.myform.ym.value.length=="")
   {
     document.myform.ym.focus();
   }
   if(document.myform.ym.value.length!=6)
   {   
     document.myform.ym.focus();
     document.getElementById("lot").value=null;
   }  
}
```

Comment: You should post your current html and css, not just javascript. You can search "javascript set css colour" and find thousands of results

Comment: As I'm posting first time here. Bdw thanks for your advice. And  next time for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For invalid and valid styles, it's as simple as `:valid` and `:invalid`. You can set up your own pattern to get the styling to understand what is valid and not.

```css
input:valid {
background:green;
}

input:invalid {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' pattern='[0-9]{6}' maxlength='6' placeholder='yyyymm'>
```

Comment: Maybe `pattern='[0-9]{6}'` and `placeholder='yyyymm'`?

Comment: Yes, mine was just as an example but no harm in changing it to what it could be :) @Watilin

Answer (score 0):

> Use of `pattern='\d{4}[/]\d{2}'`

**A)**

```css
input[type="text"]:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
} 

input[type="text"]:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' pattern='\d{4}[/]\d{2}' placeholder='yyyymm'>
```

**B)**

```css
input[type="text"]:valid + span:after{
  content: '\2714';
  color: green;
} 

input[type="text"]:invalid + span:after {
  content: '\2718';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' pattern='\d{4}[/]\d{2}' placeholder='yyyymm'> <span></span>
```

Comment: @BhardwazChetry ,  what is value that you enter?

Comment: I think OP wanted the numbers without the need for a `/`

Comment: I think the pattern you entered is just different from mine. But the code is right. Thankyou. I understand now,

Comment: @BhardwazChetry , what are you doing? first upvote , after it mark and remove all then finaly.